# Is there any difference between umask value and chmod value?

Tags: permissions, fstab, chmod

I'm using umask in fstab settings. What I know is if i set `755` with chmod, the permission will be `rwxr-xr-x`. But, when I use umask in fstab with `755` value, permission that i get is `----w--w-`. Giving `0755` doesn't seems to work.

Is there any difference between those two?

And how to give `rwxr-xr-x` permission with umask in fstab?

Answer (score 3):

You can think of `umask` as somewhat opposite to `permission`.

By default Ubuntu uses the base permission of `777` for a directory and `666` for a file. By deducting the `umask` value from the base permission you get the applied permission of a newly created file/directory.

In your case, you have given the `umask` as 755. Now as the base permission for directories is always 777, what the applied permission we get:

`777 - 755 = 022` i.e. `----w--w-`

To get your desired permission (755), you need to put the `umask` as `022`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `umask` for user as `umask u=rwx` accordingly for group and other, in case you want to use `umask` and not `chmod`.